# $_FILES is not empty but the file didn't upload

Tags: php, file

i have a form to upload a file, the code to check if it arrives is here:

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto'] ['tmp_name'])){
   echo "file is valid and was uploaded";
   print_r($_FILES);
 }
```

and it says:

```
 file is valid and was uploadedArray ( [foto] => 
 Array ( [name] => Penguins.jpg     [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name]   
 => /var/www/uploads/phpf8ECTX [error] => 0 [size] => 777835 ) ) 
 Array ( [foto] => Array ( [name] => Penguins.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] 
=> /var/www/uploads/phpf8ECTX [error] => 0 [size] => 777835 ) ) array(1) { 
["foto"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(12) "Penguins.jpg" ["type"]=> string
(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(26) "/var/www/uploads/phpf8ECTX" ["error"]
=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(777835) } }
```

but the file didnt arrive, the php.ini is configured correct and the /var/www/uploads directory have permissions to write for all users,i'm running apache2 in linux, any idea about what is wrong?
thank you

Answer (score 3):

You have to `move_uploaded_file` to the uploads directory once it is done. My understanding is that PHP will upload to a temporary folder and delete it afterwards, if you don't explicitly persist the file to a different folder.

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto'] ['tmp_name'])){
    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["foto"]["name"]))
    {
        //Maybe you want to issue an error message if the file already exists, like this.
        echo $_FILES["foto"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    }
    else
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"],
            "upload/" . $_FILES["foto"]["name"]);
    }
}
```

And remember to set up a different temporary directory for your uploads.

Comment: The check for `is_uploaded_file()` is redundant - it's included in `move_uploaded_file()`.

Answer (score 1):

is_uploaded_file() only confirms if the file you are referencing is in fact an uploaded file versus a system file, like say /etc/passwd. You can read more about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php

> Returns TRUE if the file named by filename was uploaded via HTTP POST.
>   This is useful to help ensure that a malicious user hasn't tried to
>   trick the script into working on files upon which it should not be
>   working--for instance, /etc/passwd.
>
> This sort of check is especially important if there is any chance that
>   anything done with uploaded files could reveal their contents to the
>   user, or even to other users on the same system.

After validating your file name and properties (based on your specific requirements), you must call move_uploaded_file() to move the file from it's temp location to it's permanent home.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

A good example of the actual upload script from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp):

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```